# Kendo TimePicker Initial Time in List

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-timepicker

I have a kendo DateTimePicker plugin (open source) in which it shows times from 12 AM to 11:30 PM.  I was wondering, if on clicking the time button, I could start the list at 7:30, instead of the first item of the list at 12:00 AM?  Is there a way I can have an initial value not at the first item of list, when no time has been selected?

My default registration:

```
$("#control").kendoDateTimePicker({
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
        min: new Date(1900, 1, 1)
    });
```

Comment: You can use like pickupFromTpkr.value("7.30");

Comment: That sets the value; is there a way to do it without explicitly setting the value?  That's part of the problem i'm referring to.

Comment: You can use something like this .Name("start")
          .Value("8:00 AM")
          .Min("8:00 AM")
          .Max("6:00 PM") http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/timepicker/rangeselection

Comment: @SundarRajan Value("") actually sets the value to 8 AM; I want only the user to set this, as the whole field can be left empty...  And I need a default min/max.  I also accidently wrote TimePicker earlier; I'm referring to the DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this :/ But you can still do it ugly but working way, here is the code:

```
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    open: function(e) {
        if (e.view === "time") {
            var list = $("#"+ e.sender.element.attr('id') + "_timeview");
            if(list.attr('fixed-time-labels') != 'true'){
                var elements = list.find('li:lt(15)');
                elements.insertAfter(list.find('li:last'));
                list.attr('fixed-time-labels', 'true');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and here is demo in [telerik dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oXOpE/2).

If you do not like `:lt(15)` you can take culture from kendo.culture() get time format and get li where `text == 7:30 AM` in current culture.